# Gradio button in response

Tags: python, chatbot, gradio

I'm trying to create a chatbot that I can host locally using Gradio.

I want to add a button to the output of the chatbot when it is fed certain inputs, but I can't figure out anyway to do so.

How may I go about achieving this? Or are there other libraries I can use to make this chatbot.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!